# send complex object using socket in C# but also simple text string

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, deserialization

my goal is to send simple text data and also complex data to client application using socket..this is some of my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        byte[] data;
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Welcome!!!");
        ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        ns.Flush();

        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Name = textBox1.Text;
            person.Age = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            list.Add(person);
        }

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(ns, list[a]);
        }
        ns.Flush();
 }
```

and at the client i write this code to add all data to listview

```
 private void AddToListView()
 {
         while (true && ns.DataAvailable)
         {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int recv;
            recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            textFromServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            ns.Flush();
            listView1.Items.Add(textFromServer);

            temp = formatter.Deserialize(ns) as Person;
            ns.Flush();
            listView1.Items.Add(temp.Name);
            listView1.Items.Add(temp.Age);
        }
    }
```

but when i debug the application,,nothing happens...if i delete the networkstream read() process,,the application run nicely..the problem is,i not only need to send the user object,,but also simple text to client..can someone help me please?

is it possible using networkstream.read() and binaryformatter.deserialize() at the same time??or,we have to choose one of it?

i mean when just to send/receive simple text,,we use networkstream.read()/write(),,and for complex object we use serialize/deserialize..is it possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with what you are doing is that the server and client need to have an agreed upon protocol by which to send and receive data. For instance your Client code will read everything that is available in the first ns.Read call you make. There is nothing that signals the end of one type of data and the beginning of the next, and thus you don't have an agreed upon method by which you are sending/reading data.

Easiest might be for you to encapsulate the data into another object that can contain both strings and objects.

```
[Serializable]
public class EncapsulatedData{
    public EncapsulatedData(){}
    public string Message{ get; set; }
    public ISerializable Object{ get; set; }
}
```

And you will set Object to be a ISerializable type of yours, such as Person. Then you should be able to deserialize on the client and check Message or Object.

There are cleaner ways to do this, but the above trick should work for you.

Comment: hey,,its me again..is it possible using networkstream.read() and binaryformatter.deserialize()???..or we have to choose on of them??

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ClientServer
{
    class ClientServerProgram
    {    
       public static void SendHeader(string sMIMEHeader, int iTotBytes, string sStatusCode, ref Socket mySocket)
      {
        String sBuffer = "";
        // if Mime type is not provided set default to text/html
        if (sMIMEHeader.Length == 0)
        {
            sMIMEHeader = "text/html";  // Default Mime Type is text/html
        }
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "HTTP/1.1" + sStatusCode + "\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Server: cx1193719-b\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Type: " + sMIMEHeader + "\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Length: " + iTotBytes + "\r\n\r\n";
        Byte[] bSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer);
        mySocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer),Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer).Length, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Bytes : " + iTotBytes.ToString());
      }

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncCall)
        {            
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            string messageString = "I am a little busy, come back later!";
            Byte[] message = encoding.GetBytes(messageString);

            Socket listener = (Socket)AsyncCall.AsyncState;
            Socket client = listener.EndAccept(AsyncCall);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Connection from {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint);
            SendHeader("text/html", message.Length, "202 OK", ref client);
            client.Send(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending the connection");
            client.Close();
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listener);
        }

    public static void Main()
    {
       IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.0.127.1");
       Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,  SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
       IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 8080);
       listenSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);
       listenSocket.Listen(1);
       listenSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), listenSocket);
       while (true)
       {                    
          Console.WriteLine("Waiting....");
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }                
    }
}
```